# React Warning: ReactMount: Root element has been removed from its original container. New container: [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting the error

> Warning: ReactMount: Root element has been removed from its original container. New container: [object HTMLDivElement]

Seems like something is replacing the DOM node? But not sure where the mistake is. I do not set innerHTML anywhere I can see ...

**[Code (GitHub)](https://github.com/jiewmeng/expenses-app/tree/f80c90193f50bf2d5a68921e305245f5f3afbd3a)**

I get this error when I add an expense. Code I think maybe relavent below:

**`container/addExpenseDialog.jsx`** (where `addExpense` action is dispatched)

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import AddExpenseDialogPresentation from '../presentation/expenseDialog.jsx';
import {closeDialog, addExpense} from '../../actions/index.js';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    opened: state.expenseDialog
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    doClose: () => dispatch(closeDialog()),
    // I dispatch addExpense here
    doAdd: (params) => dispatch(addExpense(params)),
  };
}

const AddExpenseDialog = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AddExpenseDialogPresentation);

export default AddExpenseDialog;
```

**`actions/index.js`**

```
export const addExpense = (expense) => {
  return Object.assign({}, expense, {
    type: 'ADD_EXPENSE'
  });
};
```

**reducers/expenses.js**

```
let id = 1;

const expense = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_EXPENSE':
      return {
        id: id++,
        name: action.name,
        category: action.category,
        cost: action.cost
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const expenses = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_EXPENSE':
      return [
        ...state,
        expense(undefined, action)
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default expenses;
```

**container/expensesList.jsx**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ExpensesListPresentation from '../presentation/expensesList.jsx';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    expenses: state.expenses
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {};
}

const ExpensesList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ExpensesListPresentation);

export default ExpensesList;
```

**`presentation/expensesList.jsx`**

```
import React from 'react';
import Expense from './expense.jsx';
import {DataTable} from 'react-mdl';
import {TableHeader} from 'react-mdl/lib/DataTable';

const ExpensesList = ({expenses}) => (
  <DataTable rows={expenses} shadow={0}>
    <TableHeader name="category">Category</TableHeader>
    <TableHeader name="name">Name</TableHeader>
    <TableHeader name="cost">Cost</TableHeader>
  </DataTable>
)

export default ExpensesList;
```

Where might I have gone wrong?

**Update**

Strangely I have dispatched add expense in `index.jsx` for some test data, and they are added fine ...

```
store.dispatch(addExpense({ name: 'X', category: 'food', cost: 10 }))
store.dispatch(addExpense({ name: 'Y', category: 'test', cost: 20 }))
store.dispatch(addExpense({ name: 'Z', category: 'food', cost: 30 }))
```

Ah!... looks like its a problem with `mdl-js-layout` ... when I remove it, layout does go off, but I dont get the error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok answering and closing this. Its actually a problem with MDL, more specifically `mdl-js-layout` class. If I remove that layout breaks, but the error also stops.